# Calculate remaining space of a box/cube

Tags: geometry, applications, packing-problem

Im developing an eCommerce system where items are 'logically' placed into boxes.
Rather than the shipping system calculating the shipping of each item individually. The shipping will be calculated by each box sent.

1,2 or more items can be placed in each box.

- Each BOX has a HxWxD (Rectangualr)
- Each item also has a HxWxD.
- A box can hold many items until full/no space left

Calculating the first item is easy, just have to figure if the item is smaller than the box, but how would I calculate the remaining space ?

Comment: Reminds of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Yes thanks. I see this is very common. I will look into the alg and see if someone has implemented this for my framework. cheers

Comment: This is a very difficult geometric packing problem (harder than the knapstack). You need to work with constraints in the 3 dimensions, and probably also with a gravity constraint: you shouldn't put a box on top of another when its balance is not achieved. Theory shows that there is no much better way than trying all possible ways to arrange the boxes.

Comment: Working with volumes is not the right way as your objects are rigid. You must work with the free width, height and depth to see if a box fits. And after you put an item, the shape of the free space becomes more complex. You'll have to represent the shape of the voids. In some cases, you need to place an item in intermediate positions (not against another item) so that later tight packing of other items is possible.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user3860921. I just wanted to let you know that I re-tagged your excellent question because, while your question does involve both algebra and geometry, the algebraic-geometry tag refers to questions about specific mathematical subfield (called algebraic geometry). When you decide on the tags for a question, you can read descriptions of what the tags mean. Choosing the most appropriate tag helps ensure that you get the best answers possible.

Comment: thanks everyone. I had no idea about the knapsack problem before posting, and yes these are all great ideas and definitly something for me to think about before implementing this in a shopping cart system.

Answer (score 1):

Even for two items the problem isn't trivial.
Let a box $W_b\times H_b\times D_b$ and a first item $W_1\times H_1\times D_1$. There could be three ways to place it in the box (or just two if you may not tilt the item, or less if the dimensions do not fit), leaving an L-shaped free space on the bottom.

And for all 3 placements, you can try 3 placements of the second item, in the two sections of the L, and also on top of the first item.

You will need to check constraints like
$$W_1+W_2\le W_b,$$
$$H_1, H_2\le H_b,$$
$$D_1, D_2\le D_b,$$
or
$$W_1+D_2\le W_b,$$
$$D_1, W_2\le H_b,$$
$$H_1, D_2\le D_b,$$
depending on the respective item orientations and the faces of contact.

(Not mentioning the possibility to place items obliquely...)